# DataTrigger from interaction not working Windows Phone

Tags: xaml, silverlight, windows-phone, interaction

I have simple example and databinding using TemplatedParent is not working. Does anyone have idea what is wrong?

```
  <Button Background="Red" Content="xD">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border>
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <ec:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=Background}" Value="Red">
                            <ec:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Background" Value="CadetBlue"/>
                        </ec:DataTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
```

No error in output. Background is supposed to be set to CadetBlue but no effect is applied.

Comment: could you be more elaborate on how it's not working? any exceptions or notified errors in ***Output*** window?

Comment: I think the `TemplatedParent` mode can be used only for `ControlTemplate`, in this case it's used for the `Border`.

Comment: It is not working as well.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `RelativeSource.TemplatedParent` works fine inside a template, but the triggers don't work as expected: if the trigger condition matches initially, the trigger/action doesn't fire.  If you change the bound property programmatically, the trigger *will* fire.  That's why it works with `IsPressed`: the button didn't start out pressed; it was pressed after it was loaded.

If you move the triggers out of the template and attach them directly to the button and adjust the bindings accordingly, everything should just work:

```
<Button x:Name="_button"
        Background="Red"
        Content="xD">
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=_button, Path=Background.Color}"
                    Value="Red">
      <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Background"
                               Value="CadetBlue" />
    </ei:DataTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
  <Button.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
      <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <ContentPresenter />
      </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Note the background trigger must bind to `Background.Color`; it doesn't work if you bind to the brush itself, possibly because `SolidColorBrush` does not override `Equals`.

Comment: How is that supposed to help me? It brings no effect. It seems that DataTrigger cannot get access to TemplatedParent or if it does it cannot change element, in this case border.

Comment: You won't see the background at all if you don't reference it in your template.  If you can't resolve `TemplatedParent`, then move the `i:Interaction.Triggers` directly under the `Button` instead of in the template.

Comment: I do not want to see it but to read it and basing on its value do some actions. I pasted simple example but normally I want to read for instance IsEnabled property and perform some actions inside template. Main concern is that I cannot reach parent template using interactions.

Comment: IsPressed is working, but try another properties like Opacity, IsEnabled, AllowDrop and so on, they aren't.

Comment: It works fine for `IsEnabled` if you set toggle it programmatically.  Looks like the triggers only fail when they match the button's initial state.  Even the background trigger works if you change the background programmatically, though the binding path has to be `Background.Color`.  This seems to be a side effect of declaring the triggers inside of a template.  If you move the triggers up to the `Button` itself, everything works fine (though you need to use `ElementName` instead of `RelativeSource`).

Comment: at first I also thought it might be the equality of the check `{Binding Background...}` against the simple `"Red"` but in fact it works for at least a simple demo that I tried. You can try it yourself, a Button with some Background set locally, a DataTrigger (inside its `Style`) listening to `Background` and a Setter setting some `Foreground`.

Comment: @KingKing Were you testing in WPF or Silverlight?

Comment: ah I tested it in WPF, so it does not work in Silverlight? weird indeed.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but all in all it does not allow me to get some information from parent and basen on it do some actions so I ended up with converter as follows :  Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=Opacity, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"